# How do I fix the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, ..."?

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception

- I created in VS Code a new classlib project.
- I added two packages to my project: `PowerShellStandard.Library` + `System.Text.Json`.

My `csproj` file contains this block:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="PowerShellStandard.Library" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My `.cs` file uses `System.Text.Json` and `System.Management.Automation`.

It does not throw me any error/warning in VS Code when I use `JsonSerializer.Serialize(...)`. It also compiles without errors or warning when running`dotnet build`. I can import it but, finally, when I run the code I receive the following error:

```
Get-JsonString : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-JsonString -input s
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-JsonString], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,UrlCSharpPowerShell.CreateJson
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What other dependencies are there? It looks like something else is referencing the `System.Text.Json` library as the version in the error message does not match the `PackageReference` version

Comment: Which .NET version are you target?

Comment: @SimplyGed, I tried to add `System.Text.Json --version 4.0.1` but it added version 4.6. Afterwards, I received the same error message. I tried to use `NewtonSoft.Json`. Even though I added this package to my csproject file VS Code throws the warning that NewtonSoft does not exist in the current context or that the namespace could not be found.
@PavelAnikhouski, I want to compile PowerShell functions with C# and want to write it for .NET Core.

Comment: A **work-around** is to use **Newtonsoft.Json**.

Comment: Did you resolve this or find the root cause?

Comment: @Dude0001, not yet. So far I am using Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: DLL Hell is still alive and well. :(

Answer (score 20):

I had this issue because I had a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` in project B that targeted *netstandard*. `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` requires `System.Text.Json` when starting .NETStandard, but not dotnetcore.

[image]

My problem came when in project A that targeted dotnetcore3.1 referenced project B. At runtime, AWS Lambda was still expecting `System.Text.Json` to be there.

To resolve the issue, I ended up switching project B to target `dotnetcore3.1` as well, even though it is a pure library and not something executable.

Not sure this answers your question directly as I don't fully understand your situation, but a possible solution for this scenario. It was a little difficult finding many other resources on this issue but I probably just don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 7):

Just install the nuget package for the **System.Text.Json** with the version number that it is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what I had to do. I had to downgrade System.Text.Json in my class library targeting netstandard2.0 to version 7.0.0. After packing the library and adding it to my .NET Framework 4.7.1 it  worked.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had a WORKING project suddenly, and without changes to the library that handled the JSON files just stop.  Would not work until I added System.Text.Json and rebuild.

Answer (score 4):

Simply update the Nuget package or System.Text.Json to 4.7.2 and onwards.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same exact error stating that it could not find system.text.json assembly version 7.0.0.

After wasting half a day I realized that I had recently update a bunge of dependencies, and that .Net 7 was also released only a 2 weeks ago. So I had updated a dependency that used system.text.json to a .NET 7 version by accident.

Solution for me was updating Visual Studio to the latest version that came with .NET 7 SDK and updating the project target framework to .NET 7

Comment: This was my exact problem as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently with the following message: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51". I had updated the nuget packages of the System.Text.Json (6.0.2) and IdentityModel (6.0.0) as part of a nuget update operation across the projects.

The culprit was the this latest version of System.Text.Json (6.0.2) which was not compatible as a dependency for IdentityModel package latest version (6.0.0), which requires System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0.

Uninstalled the IdentityModel and reinstalled it, and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I spent two days on this and it seems that you are facing a [dll hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)
basically in my case I used a plugin which attached to the main application
and internally it uses one of the packages that depends on System.Text.Json

the exception was

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

which doesn't really help but seeing the [fusionLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileloadexception.fusionlog?view=netframework-4.8) indicates that the package IdentityModel was depending on System.Text.Json so when checked the dlls was correctly there
[image]

So i have to use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) which helped me to understand which and assembly was loaded and here's the surprise we have dll hell which means my application loaded different assembly of same dll but with older version
[image]

so the solution was to downgrade the plugin to the same package that was used by the main process

Answer (score 0):

These changes in .csproj file helped me (everything else didn't) [image]

Comment: Please explain what changes you made. Red is to be added or removed? Blue-green??

Comment: @not2qubit pretty obvious - red is to be removed, green - to be added. It's default Visual Studio "git compare" screenshot.

Comment: While I understood it, it's not obvious to anyone who doesn't use any kind of `compare` software. as @not2qubit try to be as clear as possible in your answers.