# visual studio code debugger got error The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text'

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, serialization

.NET Core 3.1 have a new api `System.Text.Json` to serialize object to json

refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1

I call `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(routeValues)`, But got errors

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone know what this is?

My .NET SDK version is `3.1.302`

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Mac OS X
OS Version:  10.15
OS Platform: Darwin
RID:         osx.10.15-x64

[image]

Comment: I see another post that due the dependencies of other projects the wrong .NET was used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61621923/47351 Does that help?

Comment: Have you added a package reference to the `System.Text.Json` package?

Comment: Also note: you've shown the problem in the Watch window... what happens if you try using that code within your application itself?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added a package reference to `System.Text.Json`, `<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="5.0.2" />`, but not work,

Comment: @RvdK thanks, I'm going to use `Newtonsoft.Json`, as a workaround, thank you guys, `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(routeValues)` can work

Comment: Again, is it actually failing *in your application* or only in the Watch window? Are you using System.Text.Json anywhere in your application? (If the assembly hasn't been loaded, that would explain everything.)

Comment: @JonSkeet failing only in the Watch window, `System.Text.Json` works in application

Comment: Right. It would have been good to include that in the question. Again, my *guess* is that even in the Watch window, it would work if you've already used System.Text.Json in the application by that point.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, it is.  it would be work in WATCH window If I already used System.Text.Json in the application,